# InputText not sending new values

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a simple inputText in which I set default value by getting it from an object. After I edit inputTexts value, I push a button, which calls save method in bean. I would expect that inputText would understand that I changed its value and would change objects value as I edit it. As it turns out, I get old value, not the new (edited one) in the bean.

Maybe you have any ideas what could be the main cause of this issue?

Here is my inputText:

```
<h:inputText value="#{associationBean.counterTypeView.name}"
    id="ctpName" maxlength="100" 
    validatorMessage="#{msg['classifier.nameRequire']}">
    <f:validateRequired />
    <rich:validator />
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Could you give more details about Button and Bean?

Comment: Careully read first section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and fix your question accordingly. Among others, you have nowhere shown how you're submitting the form.

Comment: Curiously enough - I started encountering the same issue. I do not know what causes this, but I have observed that simply removing the `id` attribute makes it again work as expected. This workaround is not acceptable though, as I need the `id` for example to set the target for the `for` attribute in a `<h:outputLabel>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use JSF ajax  inside the h:inputText tag like this

```
<h:inputText value="#{associationBean.counterTypeView.name}" 
     id="ctpName" 
     maxlength="100" 
      validatorMessage="#{msg['classifier.nameRequire']}"> 
          <f:validateRequired /> 
          <rich:validator />
          <f:ajax   event="blur"/>
</h:inputText>
```

This is, on blur event of Input Text the Ajax will be called and your new data will be saved in the specified bean

Comment: Thanks! It helped. Maybe you know what I should use for `rich:select` drop down list and for `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` ?

Comment: you are welcome !! , can you please add the exact code. I have worked only with JSF 2 and ICEfaces ?

Comment: Sure. This is for `rich:select` : 
`<rich:select id="ctpMeasurementUnits"
value="#{associationBean.selectedMruId}">
 <f:selectItemsvalue="#{measurementUnitsListBean.allMeasurementUnits}"
        var="mru" itemLabel="#{mru.mruName}" itemValue="#{mru.mruId}" />
       <f:validateRequired />
       <rich:validator />
      </rich:select>`

Comment: @WheelPot what issue are you facing here , if you select any one of the select item, submit the page, you are not be able to find the value in the specified bean ?

Comment: yes, exactly that. POST send correct data, but bean gets unchanged data. Exact problem like I had with inputText.

Comment: It's required that whatever value you have in the target value of a Select control must be in the SelectItems collection. If you change the SelectItems and the old selected value isn't in the new SelectItems, you need to reset the selected value to blank, null, or an appropriate pre-selection (that is, something that's in the new SelectItems list).

Comment: That is this associationBean.selectedMruId has to instantiated

Answer (score -3):

Insert `<a4j:ajax execute="@this"/>` inside your inputText control like this

```
<h:inputText value="#{associationBean.counterTypeView.name}" 
     id="ctpName" 
     maxlength="100" 
     validatorMessage="#{msg['classifier.nameRequire']}"> 
          <f:validateRequired /> 
          <rich:validator />
          <a4j:ajax execute="@this" />
</h:inputText>
```